# How do I get my DIVs to vertically align to the top?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I’m having trouble getting one of my DIVs to vertically align to the top of what will become a navigation section.  I have this style defined …

```
#navbar {
    width: 100%; 
    font-family: Arial; 
    vertical-align: top; 
}
```

Here is the HTML behind my nav bar …

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div id="leftNavSection">
    <img alt="Logo" width="300" src="/assets/main_logo-791a416e4f99d38a339debb8dcebd7361d4172919425ace42ba2ce90336218e2.png">        
    </div>
    <div id="rightNavSection">
    Logged in as M. Bison 
    <a href="/users/edit">Edit</a>
    <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log Out</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But as you can see from my Fiddle — https://jsfiddle.net/msynjppa/ , the right section is not vertically aligning to the top.  Any help is appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I saw you were already using `float:right` on your `rightNavSection`, I went ahead and added `float:left` to your `leftNavSection`, fixing the issue. Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynnhcvxL/) and here's the CSS, the only thing I changed:

```
#navbar {
    width: 100%; 
    font-family: Arial; 
    vertical-align: top; 
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

#leftNavSection {
  float: left;
}

#rightNavSection {
   float:right;
}
```

As you can see, I also added `display:inline-block` to the `navbar`'s CSS in order to get it to display properly. Without it, the red background wouldn't show.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two `div` side-by-side then either use `float` OR use `display: inline-block`.

In your case I have defined `float: left;` for `#leftNavSection`

### Code Snippet

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: red;
}
#leftNavSection {
  float: left;
}
#rightNavSection {
  float: right;
}
#navbar::after,
#navbar::before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#navbar::after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="leftNavSection">
    <img alt="Logo" width="300" src="/assets/main_logo-791a416e4f99d38a339debb8dcebd7361d4172919425ace42ba2ce90336218e2.png">
  </div>
  <div id="rightNavSection">
    Logged in as M. Bison
    <a href="/users/edit">Edit</a>
    <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log Out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple float your image left. The image is an inline element taking the whole width of the line. Your div is floated causing it to collapse unto itself but is blocked by the inline element from rising to the top.

Remove the `vertical-align:top` cause that applies to inline elements, not block level ones such as `div`.

Comment: oops output frame was small and i didn't notice the width of image :S my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `flex-box` as it's the simplest method to do this.

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#leftNavSection,
#rightNavSection {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="leftNavSection">
    <img alt="Logo" width="300" src="/assets/main_logo-791a416e4f99d38a339debb8dcebd7361d4172919425ace42ba2ce90336218e2.png">
  </div>
  <div id="rightNavSection">
    Logged in as M. Bison
    <a href="/users/edit">Edit</a>
    <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log Out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey this works real good on my Mac Firefox.  How universal is this solution?  Do most (relatively) modern brwosers spport "display: flex;"?

Comment: Yup, it's got [pretty good support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). It's ready for production, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one also

```
#leftNavSection,
#rightNavSection
        {
            display: inline-block;
        }
```